# Change WKWebview URL with button in different ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, webview, wkwebview

I am very new to iOS development and wanted to try at building a hybrid iOS App using a webview. I'm pretty much learning as I go along and have found most answers I needed here or other websites but I've come to a point where I'm stuck.

I've got my webview setup in the main ViewController which all loads fine. I'm using a library to create a side menu which works great. However due to the way the library works, the menu is built in another ViewController. I want to populate the side menu with links that will be loaded in the webview. Is this possible?

EDIT: I should probably also mention that I'm doing this all in swift.

EDIT2: Here is a link to the framework I'm using for the Side Menu: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

The framework pretty much allows you build your own view using a tableview.

Comment: can you tell us, which framework you are using and where to find its documentation?

It should be possible using Delegate-Protocols or notifications

Comment: @FelixSFD thanks for the quick reply. I've edited the question to include a link to the side menu framework i'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I have understand your question correctly. Below is what I thought about your question:

Your MenuViewController contains a UITableView which is a list of menu, when a cell is selected, Your MainViewController's webview load a link URL, but this URL is placed in MenuViewController, right?

If this is your question, you can resolve it as these solutions:

MainViewController add a notification observer, and MenuViewController post the notification

```
// MainViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController {
let webView = UIWebView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.handleNotification(_:)), name: "OpenURL", object: nil)
}

func handleNotification(notification:NSNotification) {
    if let url = notification.userInfo?["url"] {
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url as! NSURL))
    }
}
}

// MenuViewController
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let userInfo = ["url" : your_url]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("OpenURL", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

How to use the UITableView

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Plain)
let urls = ["https://google.com", "https://youtube.com", "http://stackoverflow.com/"]
let cellIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.frame = view.bounds
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    view.addSubview(tableView)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return urls.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = urls[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let url = NSURL(string: urls[indexPath.row])!
    let userInfo = ["url" : url]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("OpenURL", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is my question. I quickly tried this however when i click on the button to open the side menu i get this error : 

"libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException."

I know this is normally to do with IB outlets not being connected but everything seems fine.

Comment: Maybe you delete or rename the IBOutlet or IBAction in your code, but the xib file still remains.

Comment: I can't seem to set MenuViewController as the class for my tableview in the storyboard. Is this because the class is missing UITableViewController in the code?

Comment: I've changed the code slightly an have now got it to build but now when i click on an item in the menu i get an error at this line **webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url as! NSURL))** the error is **Could not cast value of type 'Swift._NSContiguousString' (0x104848308) to 'NSURL' (0x102022e98).**

Comment: Ah, because url is String type, you should pass a NSURL, or cast String to NSURL with **webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url as! String)!))**

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. One last question, how can I make it so that each row in the tableview has a different url?

Comment: See the UPDATE of answer. I think you should learn how to use UITableView,  this turorial not bad [UITableView Tutorial: Dynamic Table View Cell Height](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNotification/userInfo)

First, you need to create an `UITableViewController` for the tableView that is displaying the menu items. (if you don't already have this to set the menu items programmatically; I would recommend to do this programmatically)

In the [`\[tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)\]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) method, you'll need to post a notification containing the information which item has been selected.

Example:

```
let kMenuItemSelectedNotification = "MenuItemSelected" //this should be a global constant. It identifies the notification

let infoDictionary = ["menuItem":"item1"] //a dictionary containing all information you need in your VC to change the WebView

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kMenuItemSelectedNotification, object:nil, userInfo:infoDictionary)
```

In your view controller, that contains the `WKWebView`, you need to add the observer for the notification in `viewDidLoad`.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "selector for your method:", name: kMenuItemSelectedNotification, object: nil)
```

The method you are calling with the selector handles the change of the WebView's content.

If you're not familiar with notifications yet, you should have a look at [this](http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/nsnotifications-with-userinfo-in-swift/) tutorial. It explains, how to call and recieve notifications and to handle the information sent in `userInfo`

Comment: Thanks for this. I already created the tableview in storyboard so I will look into creating it programmatically. The notifications tutorial is also useful.